# Loop works for first file then fails

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am a complete novice when it comes to scripting, but am attempting to write a batch script which runs a command to output a png file to a printer. The script I have works fine for one file, but when there are multiple files it does not.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

```
@echo off
REM ___Change Directory to where Label Is Stored___
pushd C:\AFP\to
REM ___Create Variable to capture filename of any png file___
for /F %%a in ('dir /b *.png') do set FileName=%%~na.png
REM ___Now we have the filename as a variable, send it to printer using Zebra SSDAL___
\\172.16.100.2\nDrive\Prime_DPD_Label_Print\ssdal.exe /p "TSC DA200" send %FileName% >> C:\AFP\Log\Label_Printing_Log.txt
REM ___Copy PNG File to Backup Folder___
XCOPY /y /q /c C:\AFP\to\*.png C:\AFP\backup\
REM ___Delete PNF File from To Folder___
DEL C:\AFP\to\*.png
```

When the script runs, the first file prints fine.  The subsequent files then do not print, I get "File does not exist" back from the ssdal.exe command.  Why would the first one work but not the subsequent prints?  I would have expected the for to loop through.

Comment: `) do set FileName=%%~na.png` will define the variable with a value of the first non whitespace string from the last parsed PNG filename. What you probably need to do is to open a parenthesised block and run your `do` commands within it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
REM ___Change Directory to where Label Is Stored___
pushd C:\AFP\to
REM ___Process all png files___
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.png') do (
 REM ___Now we have the filename as "%%a", send it to printer using Zebra SSDAL___
 \\172.16.100.2\nDrive\Prime_DPD_Label_Print\ssdal.exe /p "TSC DA200" send "%%a" >> C:\AFP\Log\Label_Printing_Log.txt
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  CALL ECHO SSDAL returned ERRORLEVEL %%errorlevel%% FOR "%%a"
 ) ELSE (
  REM ___Move PNG File to Backup Folder___
  IF EXIST "c:\afp\backup\%%a" (
   ECHO MOVE "%%a" to backup skipped as file already exists IN backup
  ) ELSE (
   MOVE "%%a" C:\AFP\backup\
  )
 )
 REM Two-second delay
 TIMEOUT /t 2 >nul 2>nul
)
POPD

GOTO :EOF
```

Ah! using Zebra printers. Sensible lad!

This replacement script should do what you want.

The `setlocal` command is used to ensure that any variation made by this batch to the `cmd` environment is discarded when the batch ends.

The `delims=` sets "no delimiters" so `for/f` will set `%%a` to the entire filename, even if it contains spaces or other delimiters. Quoting `%%a` ensures such filenames are kept together as a single unit, not interpreted as separate tokens.

I'm assuming that `ssdal` acts responsibly and returns `errorlevel` non-zero in the case of errors. The `if errorlevel 1` means if the errorlevel is currently `1` **or greater than `1`** and in that case, the error message is generated. We need to `call echo ... %%varname%% ...` in order to display the *current* value of the variable, if we're not using `delayed expansion` (many SO articles explain this)

Otherwise, if `ssdal` was successful, check for the existence of the filename in the `backup` directory, and either `move` it there or report that it already exists.

Of course, there are many ways in which this could be manipulated if features I've added are not desired. I'm happy to adjust this script to comply.

`timeout` is a standard utility to wait for a keypress. The redirection takes care of its prompting (it will provide a countdown unless gagged).

Comment: Thanks so much, this is great and works as expected.

Comment: I am wondering if you could help me refine this further please - is there a way to add a pause of around 2 seconds in between printing labels (running the command)?